# Add shipping fee if product is a certain SKU AND going to certain state

Tags: shipping

I'm looking for a solution or extension that will add an additional fee on top of the already existing table rate shipping costs BUT only if the product is from a certain category (or SKU) AND going to a certain state.

My client ships products all over the US but wants to add an additional $100 to products shipping to the states west of the Mississippi river (these certain products are fragile).

Hope that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is something we support fully in our shipping extensions on WebShopApps.com, I don't want to advertise here, so if you are interested drop us a mail and we will point out the relevant extension to you.

To do this programmatically you have to override the rates being returned then perform some logic to calculate the rates based on SKU's states, etc. Its do-able, just obviously there are solns out there already.

Comment: Hi Karen, which extension offers shipping price based on product SKU

Comment: I'm not allowed and do not want to advertise here.